# How to get integer index from named order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This might be really obvious but I can't find the answer.

How do you get the integer index from named order, like:

```
{ :first => 0, :second => 1, :third => 2, :fourth => 3 }
```

Is there something built in to Ruby or Rails that does this?

Thanks.

**Update**

Thanks for all your responses. Here's the solution I went with:

```
def index_for(position) 
  (0..4).to_a.send(position)
end
```

but arrays only support up to fifth, so it'll be limited to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the ordering index, you might need to combine the array and has

```
keys = [ :first, :second, :third, :fourth ]
hash = { :first => 0, :second => 1, :third => 2, :fourth => 3 }
hash.each_key { |x| puts "#{keys.index(x)}" }
```

The above method only work in 1.9 though.

Answer (score 0):

I usually keep an array of hash keys to maintain order.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ruby are you using? For Ruby 1.8, you can't because in this version a hash is an unordered colletion. This means that when you insert keys, the order is not preserved. When you iterate over the hash, the keys might be returned in a different order from the order you inserted them.

It has changed in Ruby 1.9 though.

Comment: While this is true for Ruby 1.8, it has changed in Ruby 1.9. Hash preserves insertion order in Ruby 1.9. Sorry for nitpicking :)

Comment: No, thanks for the useful information! I'll update the post to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002864) which mixes in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html).
I think *each_with_index* is what you are searching for:

```
# Calls block with two arguments, the item and its index, for each item in enum. 

hash = Hash.new
%w(cat dog wombat).each_with_index {|item, index|
  hash[item] = index
}
hash   #=> {"cat"=>0, "wombat"=>2, "dog"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

For followers, the linguistics gem apparently can do something like this as well [How to convert 1 to "first", 2 to "second", and so on, in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940814/ruby-how-to-convert-1-to-first-2-to-second)