# How to loop through multiple arrays that correspond with each other in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How would you incorporate multiple arrays into one loop? I want them to iterate over just one at a time at the same time.

example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [a, b, c, d]
c = [w, x, y, z]
```

desired output:

"on the **1st** day, there was a **1** on **a**. Add **w**."

"on the **2nd** day, there was a **2** on **b**. Add **x**."

"on the **3rd** day, there was a **3** on **c**. Add **y**."

"on the **4th** day, there was a **4** on **d**. Add **z**."

Also, can we incorporate .each_with_index? Because I also need the index number to be printed in the loop. The number in "on the 1st/2nd/etc day" is where I would input #{index + 1}.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. SO isn't a code-writing service, it's more of a code-debugging site, where we help you fix code you've written. So, show us your attempts, explain why they didn't work and then we'll try to help.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 7):

This is what [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) is for:

```
a.zip(b)
# => [ [ 1, 'a' ], [ 2, 'b' ], ... ]
```

Now you can just iterate over that:

```
a.zip(b).each.with_index(1) do |(was, on), day|
  # ... Print message
end
```

Where here you can use `.each.with_index(1)` to specify a starting index, where `each_with_index`, for whatever reason, does not allow that.

Comment: What if there are 3 arrays? Thank you

Comment: Add another argument to `zip`, as in `zip(b, c)`.

Comment: so when you print out the message how would that look like?
a.zip(b).each.with_index(1) do |(was, on), day|
  puts "on the #{day}, there was a #{was} on #{on}." 
this did not work for me, it only gave me info from the first array (a)

Comment: @Karen `a.zip(b, c).each.with_index(1) { |(i, j, k), day| ... }` should work. Within the block, `i`, `j`, and `k` correspond to the respective values in `a`, `b`, and `c`. Rename the variables as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.with_index`
For example:

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

a.map.with_index do |item,  index|
  puts "on the #{index + 1}th day, there was a #{index + 1} on #{b[index]}."
end
```

Output would be like a

```
on the 1th day, there was a 1 on a.
on the 2th day, there was a 2 on b.
on the 3th day, there was a 3 on c.
on the 4th day, there was a 4 on d.
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Also you can use with some arrays:

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
c = [:foo, :bar, :fu, :bar]

a.map.with_index do |item,  index|
  puts "on the #{index + 1}th day, there was a #{index + 1} on #{b[index]} with #{c[index]}."
end
```

It will returns

```rb
on the 1th day, there was a 1 on a with foo.
on the 2th day, there was a 2 on b with bar.
on the 3th day, there was a 3 on c with fu.
on the 4th day, there was a 4 on d with bar.
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

So, if you want to return string instead of puts it you just need to remove `puts` from block

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
c = [:foo, :bar, :fu, :bar]

a.map.with_index do |item,  index|
  "on the #{index + 1}th day, there was a #{index + 1} on #{b[index]} with #{c[index]}."
end
```

It will returns Array

```
=> ["on the 1th day, there was a 1 on a with foo.", "on the 2th day, there was a 2 on b with bar.", "on the 3th day, there was a 3 on c with fu.", "on the 4th day, there was a 4 on d with bar."]
```

Comment: For some reason it's giving me blanks. It just skips over the number. Any idea why?

Comment: @Karen didn't get it. You want to puts strings, or return array of strings?

Comment: If you want to return strings from array, you need to remove `puts` from iterator block.
```ruby
a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
c = [:foo, :bar, :fu, :bar]

a.map.with_index do |item,  index|
  "on the #{index + 1}th day, there was a #{index + 1} on #{b[index]} with #{c[index]}."
end
```

Comment: I want it to come out exactly as you have it. but instead the output reads "on the 1th day, there was a on with."
It doesn't retrieve the info from the arrays

Comment: @Karen could you please provide code that you execute.

Comment: BTW, it's "2nd" and "3rd", not "2th" and "3th".

Comment: @Stefan pluralization it's another topic I believe. But anyway, it's easy to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940814/how-to-convert-1-to-first-2-to-second-and-so-on-in-ruby

Comment: You could use `"on day #{index + 1} there was ..."` in your answer and avoid the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = %w|a b c d|  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"] 
c = %w|w x y z|  #=> ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

```
a.each_index do |i|
  puts "on day %d, there was a %d on %s. Add %s." % [i+1, a[i], b[i], c[i]]
end
on day 1, there was a 1 on a. Add w.
on day 2, there was a 2 on b. Add x.
on day 3, there was a 3 on c. Add y.
on day 4, there was a 4 on d. Add z.
```

or

```
[a,b,c].transpose.each.with_index(1) do |arr,i|
  puts "on day %d, there was a %d on %s. Add %s." % [i,*arr]
end
on day 1, there was a 1 on a. Add w.
on day 2, there was a 2 on b. Add x.
on day 3, there was a 3 on c. Add y.
on day 4, there was a 4 on d. Add z.
```

Note

```
[a,b,c].transpose
  #=> [[1, "a", "w"],
  #    [2, "b", "x"],
  #    [3, "c", "y"],
  #    [4, "d", "z"]]
```